# Magento 2.2 Shopping options sidebar should display on sub category

Tags: category, magento2.2, layered-navigation

[image]

Currently this shopping options displays only on main category page.
How to display this shopping options under sub category page navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Anchor` to `Yes` under `Catalog -> Categories -> <category_name> -> Display Settings`

- Check other Design and Display settings are correct.
- Check if there are products in the category.

Comment: By default its enabled in all categories

Comment: Check if display and design settings are correct for categories. Because if it is enabled then it should appear.

Comment: I have added the answer.Is that correct method.

Comment: No, it is not the correct way. Check why it is not showing and which condition is getting failed.

Comment: <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?> this conditions fails to display filters on sub category page

Comment: This means that there are no items to display. Add few items in the category and check again. Make sure attributes that are included in layered navigation has some values for products.

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept, if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by

> \Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\view.phtml

add else section for **($block->canShowBlock())**
copy the same code under else section and remove the condition **?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>**